# Django MySql - combining only() and distinct()

Tags: python, mysql, django

This is my model in Django.

```
class Meta_Columns(models.Model):
    cur_parent=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cur_child=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cur_child_label=models.CharField(max_length=200)
    cur_childisparent= models.BooleanField()
    cur_childtype= models.CharField(max_length=200,choices=CHILD_TYPE)
    cur_Misc= models.CharField(max_length=200,blank=True)

    class Admin:
        pass
```

I want to select the `'cur_parent'` column and get the distinct values (from MySql)

Below is the code.

```
if request.method == 'POST':    
        all_parents =  Meta_Columns.objects.only("cur_parent").distinct("cur_parent")
        data = serializers.serialize("json", all_parents)
        return HttpResponse(data, content_type='application/json')
```

If i make the call to the view, this is the error i get.

`DISTINCT ON fields is not supported by this database backend`

I cannot use `values("field_name").distinct()` because it will not work with json & this error is thrown : `'dict' object has no attribute '_meta'`.

How to get distinct values then?

Answer (score 0):

Django's `serializers.serialize()` expects Django model instances as inputs, and `distinct()` won't be returning that (even more so because `cur_parent` is not a ref to a model, but a `CharField`)

If `.values('cur_parent')` works for you, you can just serialize that list of distinct parents with a regular JSON serializer, e.g.

```
import json

all_parents =  Meta_Columns.objects....values('cur_parent').distinct()
json_str = json.dumps(all_parents) # Works with regular data structure,
                                   # doesn't need to be a Django model instance

return HttpResponse(json_str, content_type='application/json')
```